# Writing values to Textboxes on Chart Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, charts

Looking for some guidance. I have created a statistics chart but also it lists the Top 5 WIP for certain categories.

the trouble I'm having is writing to text boxes on a chart. I have managed to do it with standard text boxes found on the insert tab but not with the ActiveX boxes which is what I need due to the need of scroll bars

Here is the function I have written to write strings to all text boxes.

```
Function Top5HeldCell(aSheet)

Dim row As Integer
Dim commentBox As TextBox


row = 12

For i = 4 To GetNumberOfEntries(aSheet, "A")

    If Sheets(aSheet).Range("S" & i).Value <> "" Then

        If Sheets(aSheet).Range("T" & i).Value = "" Then

            rmNumber = Sheets(aSheet).Range("A" & i).Value
            partNumber = Sheets(aSheet).Range("B" & i).Value
            serialNumber = Sheets(aSheet).Range("C" & i).Value
            ncNumber = Sheets(aSheet).Range("D" & i).Value
            currentWIP = Sheets(aSheet).Range("W" & i).Value
            Comments = Sheets(aSheet).Range("I" & i).Value

            If row <= 16 Then

                ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("rmNumber" & row)).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = rmNumber

                ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("partNumber" & row)).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = partNumber

                ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("serialNumber" & row)).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = serialNumber

                ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("ncNumber" & row)).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ncNumber

                ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("WIPTime" & row)).Select
                Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = currentWIP
                ' This works using standard textboxes
                'ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("comment" & row)).Select
                'Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Comments

                ' here I'm trying to use ActiveX boxes
                Charts("Statistics Chart").OLEObjects("comment" & row).Object.Text = ""

                row = row + 1

            End If

        End If

    End If

Next i

End Function
```

I seem to be getting the error 'Unable to get OLEObjects property of the Chart Class.

From using my nogging I expect this is something to do with the Charts not supporting this feature. Is there a work around that is known or am I really stuck???

Cheers

Comment: May I see your file?

Comment: How exactly did you add ActiveX textboxes to a chart sheet?

Comment: renamed them on a standard sheet and then copied them in

Comment: Siddharth Rout - Unfortunately not. The file contains contents from work.

Comment: It might be simpler all round to put the chart on a normal worksheet. You can hide rows and columns outside your desired area to mimic the appearance of a chart sheet.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey - just gave that ago :-) still get an error though 'Unable to get the OLEObjects property of Worksheet Class' 'code' Sheets("Statistics Chart").OLEObjects("comment" & row).Object.Text = Comments 'code'

Comment: @demonLaMagra The fact that you had to do that should have been a clue. ;) You can't have an activex control on a chart sheet - what you pasted is a picture.

Comment: @Rory - Yep that was it! So I have now moved the chart to a standard sheet and remade the text boxes and it now works. Microsoft could do with fixing this as it would be a nice addition to charts.